# Does $X$ being path-connected and contractible mean the fundamental group of $X$ is trivial?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I just started learning algebraic topology recently.I'm not sure if I got the idea correctly.Hope someone would check it.

My solution:Since $X$ is contractible and path-connected,then $X$ is simply connected.Thus $\pi_{1}(X)$ is trivial.

Does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $X$ is simply connected is what you should prove. Note that $X$ is always path connected if it is contractible: suppose that $id_X \simeq c_{x}$ for some $x \in X$ via a homotopy

$$
H : X \times I \to X,
$$

which satisfies $H_0 = id$ and $H_1 = c_{x}$. For any $y \in X$, the map $H(y,-)$ is a path from $y$ to $x$.

To show that $\pi_1(X)$ you can see that moreover we have $X \simeq *$,

> **Hint:** there is a unique map $X \to *$. As for maps $* \to X$, they correspond to a selection of some point of $X$. *There aren't many to choose*. Using the fact that $X$ is contractible  you can prove that both compositions are homotopic to the identities.

Comment: Care needs to be taken with basepoints. It is not true that a contractible space with an arbitrary basepoint is terminal in the “naive” homotopy category of basepointed spaces. Nevertheless, it is true that the fundamental group of a contractible space is trivial.

Comment: @ConnorMalin if we consider $\mathsf{Top}$ instead of $\mathsf{Top}_\ast$, then $X$ should indeed be final, no? As for the pointed case, I'd be interested to know about a counterexample, if you wouldn't mind providing one.

Comment: I am saying that if you take contractible to be the definition without mentioning basepoints, then there are contractible spaces in $hTop_*$ (where maps are basepointed homotopy classes of maps) which are not terminal. Terminal objects here are maps that are contractible while keeping the basepoint fixed. An example of such a space is the comb space with basepoint not on the base of the comb. This is because there are at least two maps from this space to itself (the identity and the constant map).

Comment: Got it, very interesting. So an alternative definition of contractible (taking basepoints into account) would be that $id \simeq c_x \text{ rel $x$}$ for some $x$, and these are the final objects in $\mathsf{hTop}_\ast$?

Comment: Not rel just any x, rel the basepoint. These are final in the category I described. I am careful in how I refer to these categories because something like $hTop_*$ can mean something more subtle where the morphisms include formal inverses to weak homotopy equivalences. If this is the case, it ends up being that all contractible spaces are final because any map between contractible spaces induces a isomorphism on homotopy groups because, like the original question asked, the homotopy groups of a contractible space end up being trivial, but not for a simple categorical reason.

Comment: I think I see it. Do you have any good recommendations for an introduction to homotopical algebra? I know the basics of $1$-category theory (i.e. Riehl's Category Theory in Context minus the section on Kan Extensions).

Comment: What I am reading is called “Homotopy+Algebra=Operads”, but I’m getting motivation first from May’s iterated loop spaces.

Comment: I'll check that out. Many thanks!